# Defining aliases with byobu

Tags: byobu, alias

I want to have a few aliases for my byobu sessions, but I'm not sure where in the byobu files I'm supposed to put the commands (`alias <name> <command>`).

Answer (score 2):

Just put it in your `~/.bashrc` or other shell's rc file!